# .Request() command for a GraphServiceClient is giving me an error in Visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-graph-teams

I am going through a manual on how to Build .NET apps with Microsoft Graph.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=2
And I am reaching an issue:

A am at an instruction where we send a request to access the clients information. But I can't seem to type the .Request().Select coommand in the first place.
This image shows my issue. But I have installed the Microspft.Graph package for this to work.
What am I missing here?
[Here is an image of the code to look at as well as the packages I have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRI0v.png)
[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uO9v.png)
Any help apricated, Thanks!

I tried recreating the project. Re-installing packages. And even running the project on a new windows machine but still reach the same issue.

Comment: What is the error, and could you please post your code here in text?

Comment: GraphServiceClient uses OAuth2 authentication and needs a key before attempting to get a token.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user